# How UserDetails from UserDetailsService compare data passed via user in html form

Tags: spring, security, userdetailsservice

I have:

```
@Service
public class MyAppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private IUserInfoDAO userInfoDAO;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User activeUserInfo                   = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
    GrantedAuthority authority            = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());


    String userNameVal                    = activeUserInfo.getUserName();
    String userSurnameVal                 = activeUserInfo.getPassword();

    UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userNameVal, userSurnameVal, Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
}
```

and:

in security chain I configured:

```
   .and().formLogin()  //login configuration
                .loginPage("/app/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/app-login")
                .usernameParameter("app_username")
                .passwordParameter("app_password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/secure/projects-details")
```

How user password fill in the form is compare to UserDetails set in loadUserByUsername method?

Answer (score 2):

Once you tell the Spring Security Configuration that you will use a particular `UserDetailsService` or only one `@Service` bean is an implementation of that interface, then Spring starts using it to fetch the user by username from your persistent storage. Let's simplify the flow:

1. The user submits a form where fields with names `app_username` and `app_password` are present (as configured in Web Security Config) to the `loginPage(String)` route
2. The form submission is intercepted by the Spring Security's Filter Chain and Spring is aware that the **username** is in the field `app_username` and the **password** is in the field `app_password`
3. The configured `UserDetailsService` bean is now activated, at its `loadUserByUsername(String)` method is invoked and the value of `app_username` field is passed (e.g. `john_smith`)
4. As the `loadUserByUsername(String)` method is by contract designed to return an implementation of `UserDetails` it always returns an object which contains `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` methods
5. Spring then uses the `getPassword()` method from the contract and compares the password with `app_password` field (e.g. `super_s3cr3t_password`)
6. If `passwordEncoder()` is configured in the Spring Security Config or an implementation of `PasswordEncoder` interface is registered as bean, then spring uses the `isPasswordValid(String, String, Object)` method to verify the contents of `app_password` field and the result of `UserDetails.getPassword()` method
7. If the `UserDetailsService` does not throw `UsernameNotFoundException` and the fetched `UserDetails`'s `getPassword()` matches the `app_password` the filter chain continues executing the other filters, otherwise it prevents the user from logging into the application

If a code example simplifies it better, then imagine the following pseudo-java-code:

```
String usernameField = this.getConfiguredUsernameParameter(); // app_username
String passwordField = this.getConfiguredPasswordParameter(); // app_password
UserDetails userDetails = this.registeredUserDetailsImplementation.loadUserByUsername(request.getParameter(usernameField));
String passwordHash = userDetails.getPassword();
String rawPassword = request.getParameter(passwordField);
String salt = this.getConfiguredSalt(); // can be null
if (this.configuredPasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(passwordHash, rawPassword, salt) {
   return true;
}

return false;
```

Keep in mind this is not the Spring Security Code behind the scenes, but just a simplified code illustration of the explanation.

Comment: txt for the answer!